# Iterating over an array cast as void*

Tags: c, casting, void-pointers

I create an array:

```
unsigned short* array = malloc(sizeof(unsigned short)*N);
```

Assign values to it:

```
for(i=0; i<N; i++){
    array[i] = rand()%USHRT_MAX;
}
```

Cast it to a void* and pass it to a worker thread which will find the max value in the array:

```
pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, findMax, (void*)&array);
```

Which looks like this:

```
void* findMax(void* arg){
    int i = 0;
    unsigned short max = 0;
    unsigned short* table = (unsigned short*)arg;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        if(table[i]> max){
            max = table[i];
        }
    }
    printf("Max: %d\n", max);
}
```

The issue is that the numbers assigned in the array are misformatted. For example with the N randomly generated numbers: 3664 50980 37495 12215 33721, this loop will interpret the numbers as following instead:

```
table[0] = 28680
table[1] = 2506
table[2] = 5
table[3] = 0
table[4] = 32736
```

With the 5 and 0 as recurring pattern on the 2nd and 3rd place in the array.

I'm clearly overstepping some memory boundries, what is happening here and how do I fix it?

Comment: when you are passing the parameter in the pthread_create, the variable is already a pointer, so you should just pass (void*)array

Comment: The cast to `void *` in `(void*)&array` or `(void*)array`, and the cast to `(unsigned short * )` in `(unsigned short*)arg` are not needed in C.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change:

```
(void*)&array
```

to this:

```
(void*)array
```

since `void* findMax(void* arg)` expects a pointer, and you were passing the address of the pointer.

Comment: And you don't even need to cast.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer variable is a variable declared with a derived type specifier.
It is still a variable and it still has an address.
The value on that address is an address of a variable of that type.

A "pointer type" usually refers to `void*` while short pointer to `short*` and so on. void pointers can point to any variable, but you will have to convert it to a pointer of a generic type, when using it, using type-casting,
therefore you only cast void* when you are converting it to something else.

So if you add ampersand (reference) operator to a pointer `&ptr` you are ultimately referencing to the address of the pointer variable. It can be useful if you want to "repoint" the pointer from within a function.

Your code can still succeed, but you will have to declare the arguments differently:

( `foo(void** vp)` )
And to access the variable it points to, you dereference the void**:

`void* p = *vp;`